# Go back and make changes to the filled form?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible for people who filled out the form to go back to their form and make changes?

I am looking for this type of form for my website. I think they will need a password or something like that. It is obvious that it will save all the inquiries, still I need that type of form.

Answer (score 1):

We are adding support for sharing view/edit links to existing entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in the next two weeks.  You can already enable Save & Resume to support saving progress and resuming later before submitting entries.

This feature takes this capability way further by allowing you to include secure links on the confirmation page, confirmation emails, and shared when managing entries that allow anyone to view and/or edit individual entries without logging into Cognito Forms.  You can also use conditional logic to automatically disable these links to support your internal workflow processes.

https://trello.com/c/pbrbGrft